# Evasiveness of acyclicity of undirected graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, lower-bounds

The [lecture note](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/29-adversary.pdf) by Jeff Erickson discusses "Evasive Graph Properties":

> We call a graph property *evasive* if we have to look at all $\binom{n}{2}$ entries in the adjacent matrix to decide whether an (undirected) graph has that property.

As an example, it shows that connectivity is evasive.

I want to know: Is acyclicity evasive? How to prove/disprove it?

---

*My attempt:* A rather straightforward adaptation I made from the proof for connectivity does not work for acyclicity.

Comment: This appears to be exercise 4 in the lecture notes you linked.  That exercise gives a hint.  I haven't verified whether the hint is helpful, but it seems worth a try.  Also, Conjecture 1 in those lecture notes also suggests that it ought to be true, which says to me it's worth focusing on finding a proof (rather than a disproof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any algorithm for acyclicity. We will use the following adversary:

> Whenever the algorithm asks for an edge, say that the edge exists if it connects two different connected components. (That is, if it doesn't close a cycle.)

You can show that the graph constructed by this dialog is always a forest, and moreover the constructed graph has the same connected components as the query graph (which contains all queried edges). In particular, when the last edge is asked, the graph is a tree (assuming $n \geq 3$; otherwise every graph is acyclic), and the graph is acyclic if and only if this edge does not belong to the graph.